# make it a function

Tags: r, function

With the help of SO I now have a way of renaming a all variables in a data frame, except a selected subset. I'm currently using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662314/r-rename-subset-of-variables-in-data-frame/10669726#10669726), please see blow (thanks to [flodel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201032/flodel)).

I would like to write a function where I can define 1) my data, 2) a vector of variables and 3) what prefix I would like added to the variables not selected in the function (see my attempt below). I mistakenly thought this would be easy, but I have a really hard time getting the function to work.

Here is my attempt at writing the function, which is clearly not working. Also, if anyone would recommend a site or some text I could read to better understand how to write functions.

```
baRadd <- function(df, vector, suffix){names(df) <- 
                   ifelse(names(df) %in% vector,names(df), 
                   paste(suffix, names(df), sep = ".")) }

data(mtcars)
temp.mtcars <- mtcars
baRadd(temp.mtcars, c("mpg", "cyl", "disp"), "baR")
```

Initial function form flodel

```
data(mtcars)
# head(mtcars)

temp.mtcars <- mtcars
names(temp.mtcars) <- ifelse(names(mtcars) %in% c("mpg", "cyl", "disp"),
                         names(mtcars),
                         paste("baR", names(mtcars), sep = "."))
str(temp.mtcars)
'data.frame': 32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg     : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl     : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp    : num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ baR.hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ baR.drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ baR.wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ baR.qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ baR.vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ baR.am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ baR.gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ baR.carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is that your function doesn't return any value. It simply modifies the data.frame `df`, (which is local to the evaluation environment) and then exits.

To get it to return the modified object, do something like this:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars1 <- mtcars

baRadd <- function(df, vector, suffix){ 
                   names(df) <- ifelse(names(df) %in% vector,names(df), 
                                      paste(suffix, names(df), sep = ".")) 
                   return(df)}

mtcars1 <- baRadd(mtcars1, c("mpg", "cyl", "disp"), "baR")
```

A **better** solution (in my opinion) would be to write a function that creates a modified vector of names, which you can then assign to the existing data.frame.

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars
baRadd2 <- function(df, vector, suffix){ 
                    newnames <- ifelse(names(df) %in% vector,names(df), 
                                       paste(suffix, names(df), sep = ".")) 
                    return(newnames)}

names(mtcars2) <- baRadd2(mtcars2, c("mpg", "cyl", "disp"), "baR")
```

Comment: Thanks, guess I never figured out the `return()`. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. You don't actually need the `return()`. If it's missing, the function will return the value of its last line. So, in the second example above, you could just as well: (a) change the last line to `newnames`; or (b) remove the last line, and the assignment to `newnames` (i.e. this bit: `newnames <- `).  I just tend to include the `return()` as an explicit visual cue about what's being returned. Cheers.