# dcast renaming all variables to start with a number

Tags: r, data.table, reshape2

So I've got data that looks like this:

```
           id year principal interest
 1: 011000600 2013      0.00     0.00
 2: 011000600 2014    544.03     0.00
 3: 011000700 2013      0.00     0.00
 4: 011000700 2014      0.01     0.00
 5: 011000800 2013    363.44    12.79
 6: 011000800 2014   2005.98     0.00
 7: 011000900 2013      0.00     0.00
 8: 011000900 2014      0.00     0.00
 9: 011001000 2013      0.00     0.00
10: 011001000 2014      0.00     0.00
11: 011001100 2013      0.00     0.00
12: 011001100 2014   1723.24     0.00
13: 011001560 2013      0.00     0.00
14: 011001560 2014      0.00     0.00
15: 011001650 2013      0.00     0.00
16: 011001650 2014      0.00     0.00
```

(basically a longitudinal sample of a bunch of variables)

The data is on the large side so I'm using `data.table` for everything. I reshape it to get each `id` unique by row:

```
datam<-melt(data,id=c("id","year"))
data1<-dcast.data.table(datam,id~...)
```

This yields:

```
          id 2013_principal 2013_interest 2014_principal 2014_interest
1: 011000600           0.00          0.00         544.03             0
2: 011000700           0.00          0.00           0.01             0
3: 011000800         363.44         12.79        2005.98             0
4: 011000900           0.00          0.00           0.00             0
5: 011001000           0.00          0.00           0.00             0
6: 011001100           0.00          0.00        1723.24             0
```

This is course the *form* of data that I want, but having column names start with numbers is a pain in the keester.

Any suggestions for how to deal with this? I'd much rather have:

```
          id principal_2013 interest_2013 principal_2014 interest_2014
1: 011000600           0.00          0.00         544.03             0
2: 011000700           0.00          0.00           0.01             0
3: 011000800         363.44         12.79        2005.98             0
4: 011000900           0.00          0.00           0.00             0
5: 011001000           0.00          0.00           0.00             0
6: 011001100           0.00          0.00        1723.24             0
```

(switching the year to be a suffix)
I've tried being more explicit when casting, e.g.

```
data2<-dcast.data.table(datam,id~year+...)
data3<-dcast.data.table(datam,id~...+year)
```

To no avail:

```
data2
          id 2013_principal 2013_interest 2014_principal 2014_interest
1: 011000600           0.00          0.00         544.03             0
2: 011000700           0.00          0.00           0.01             0
3: 011000800         363.44         12.79        2005.98             0
4: 011000900           0.00          0.00           0.00             0
5: 011001000           0.00          0.00           0.00             0
6: 011001100           0.00          0.00        1723.24             0

data3
          id 2013_principal 2013_interest 2014_principal 2014_interest
1: 011000600           0.00          0.00         544.03             0
2: 011000700           0.00          0.00           0.01             0
3: 011000800         363.44         12.79        2005.98             0
4: 011000900           0.00          0.00           0.00             0
5: 011001000           0.00          0.00           0.00             0
6: 011001100           0.00          0.00        1723.24             0
```

Seems pretty silly for the naming convention of dcast to default to this style, given that I imagine this type of reshaping is ubiquitous.

I've also tried patching things up ex-post given some other posts I've found (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662314/r-rename-subset-of-variables-in-data-frame)), but it runs unfathomably slow (there are ~400 variables to rename in the full data set)

```
names(data)<-ifelse(substr(names(data),1,2) %in% c("19","20"),    
                    paste(substr(names(data),6,nchar(data)),
                          substr(names(data),1,4),sep="_")   ,
                    names(copy))
```

(I'm trying to find all the variables starting with years--19xx or 20xx--and trying to swap the beginning and end)

Comment: That worked @Arun. Would you mind giving an explanation why? I've never understood the variable syntax in the dcast documentation. Also, the value.var="value" part seems extraneous. Why include it?

Comment: I see. Why then didn't the 3rd attempt work: 
data3<-dcast.data.table(datam,id~...+year)?
I thought ... was supposed to black box every other variable, but I guess this is what variable does?

Comment: in retrospect, a much better way of renaming them ex-post would be `setnames(data,gsub("([^_]*)_(.*)","\\2_\\1",names(data)))` (or boutique variations thereof), but the below solutions are better suited to nipping the problem in the bud.

Comment: Michael, with the new developments, it'd be nice if you could accept the new answer, as it's the idiomatic way to do things hereafter with data.tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even better, with the new developments to `dcast` in data.table from [v1.9.5+](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation), we can cast multiple columns simultaneously..

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
dcast(dt, id ~ year, value.var = c("principal", "interest"))
#          id principal_2013 principal_2014 interest_2013 interest_2014
# 1: 11000600           0.00         544.03          0.00             0
# 2: 11000700           0.00           0.01          0.00             0
# 3: 11000800         363.44        2005.98         12.79             0
# 4: 11000900           0.00           0.00          0.00             0
# 5: 11001000           0.00           0.00          0.00             0
# 6: 11001100           0.00        1723.24          0.00             0
# 7: 11001560           0.00           0.00          0.00             0
# 8: 11001650           0.00           0.00          0.00             0
```

No more having to `melt` unnecessarily before to `cast`, therefore quite efficient.

Comment: How could I then specify that I'd like both principal and interest to go before 2013, 2014 etc.?

Answer (score 3):

#### [FR #5675](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5675&group_id=240&atid=978) is now implemented in v1.9.3. From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?root=datatable&r1=1263&r2=1264)

> o  `dcast.data.table(dt, a ~ ... + b)` now generates the column names with values from 'b' coming last. Closes #5675.

That is, now you can do:

```
dcast.data.table(datam, id ~ ... + year)

#          id principal_2013 principal_2014 interest_2013 interest_2014
# 1: 11000600           0.00         544.03          0.00             0
# 2: 11000700           0.00           0.01          0.00             0
# 3: 11000800         363.44        2005.98         12.79             0
# 4: 11000900           0.00           0.00          0.00             0
# 5: 11001000           0.00           0.00          0.00             0
# 6: 11001100           0.00        1723.24          0.00             0
# 7: 11001560           0.00           0.00          0.00             0
# 8: 11001650           0.00           0.00          0.00             0
```

and the column names will have `year` values at the end, as expected.

---

#### Also added documentation - [Doc #5676](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5676&group_id=240&atid=5356). From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?root=datatable&r1=1263&r2=1264):

> o  ?dcast.data.table now explains how the names are generated for the columns that are being casted. Closes #5676.

Now `?dcast.data.table` contains the added line:

> Names for columns that are being cast are generated in the same order (separated by a _) from the (unique) values in each column mentioned in the formula RHS.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

@Arun's solution is to explicitly set the right hand of the formula to the order that you wish to name the columns.

```
data1 <- dcast.data.table(datam,id ~ variable+year, value.var="value")
```