# dcast renames numeric id variables

Tags: r, reshape2

I have the following problem:

The data is in long format and I use dcast for wide format.
Some but not all of my ID variables are numeric, and they have an X in front afterwards which I cannot easily get rid of because some character ID vairables also start with X and variable names lengths can differ, too. For example, 123 becomes X123.

Here is an example code:

```
x=data.frame(c("2000-01-01","2000-06-01","2001-01-01"),c("XYZ","123","456"),c(200,200,200))
colnames(x)=c("Date","Ticker","Price")


x2=data.frame(dcast(x, "Date ~ Ticker", value.var="Price",fun.aggregate=mean))
```

This is what I get:

```
> x2
        Date X123 X456 XYZ
1 2000-01-01  NaN  NaN 200
2 2000-06-01  200  NaN NaN
3 2001-01-01  NaN  200 NaN
```

This is what I want:

```
> x2
        Date 123 456 XYZ
1 2000-01-01  NaN  NaN 200
2 2000-06-01  200  NaN NaN
3 2001-01-01  NaN  200 NaN
```

Note: I would like to use base R to solve this issue (together with reshape2).

The following link did not help me, and I could not find any info on the reshape2 pdf.

[dcast renaming all variables to start with a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552780/dcast-renaming-all-variables-to-start-with-a-number)

Comment: `dcast(x, "Date ~ Ticker", value.var="Price",fun.aggregate=mean)` why do you need to wrap with data.frame, it is already a data.frame.  Also, while using `data.frame`, you can use `check.names=FALSE`

Comment: or `tidyr::spread(x, Ticker, Price)`

Comment: Hi Akrun, the data.frame was inherited because the code was written when reshape2 was not available (I think that cast did not automatically write a data.frame). However, thanks a lot for the solution!!!

Comment: @jeremycg that would work for the example but `spread` won't calculate the mean as desired.

Comment: @fuji2015 Thanks for the response.  I haven't checked with `cast` from `reshape`.

Comment: @Akrun: You were right, I switched the code to reshape2 without deleting the data.frame.

Comment: Do you have maybe an idea why `check.names=FALSE` does not work together with `fun.aggregate=function(x) prod(x)` in `dcast` while it works perfectly with `fun.aggregate=mean` ? The error message `unused argument (check.names = FALSE)` appears